# Spark out of memory issue while writing to many files in Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, parquet

We have facing out of memory issue with spark while writing dataframe content to hive table in loop.

The code we used

```
df.write.insertInto(hiveTable);
```

We getting an exception of

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

We configured the memory as

```
--executor-memory 10g and num-executors 6
```

When looking to spark UI application not taking more than 70MB all over, driver memory of 7to 10 MB and all executors 60MB.

Something related to yarn AM.

We have changed the configuration by

```
--conf "spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summay-metadata=false"
```

And by this change we improved the performance but it's againg failed when we increase the number of write to same hive table

We running the spark application in client mode with spark-submit command. And we are using cloudera 1.6.0 as spark version.

Please suggest

Comment: Could you tell us how the dataframe is built? and maybe the minimal amount of code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Data frame is loaded from CSV files. Each file having max of 100mb size.

Comment: We can reproduce it by creating 1000 csv file and write it to hive db using spark dataframes

Comment: DO you read the files from the driver (sc.parallelize ) or with the workers (sc.textFile, sc.wholeTextFile...) ?

Comment: From worker. sc.wholeTextFile.

Comment: We might be on to something. How big are the files?

Comment: Maximum of 100mb. I have increased the driver memory now and it process more number of files. I had given --driver-memory 5g but 2.7 memory is allotted to storage memory and application not using that memory. Whether we can allot that memory to   driver?

Comment: Just to see if the error persists, could you try using sc.textFile("...") instead (you only won't be able to use the name of the files)?